# Balance two dataset for training

Tags: python, dataset

Currently, I am working on the Age Classification problem.

Suppose that I have 2 datasets,for example, A and B. The dataset A contains approximately 160k images while set B only contains 5k images.

- The train set A is downloaded from Internet. Every image is perfectly
  labelled with a specific age range. For instance, 7 age groups in total.
- The set B is manually labelled from real scenario (video
  camera). A lot of noisy images and small size image. (45x45)
- The test set C is similar to train set B (real case) (It's private set)

I applied the transfer learning technique, but I got poor performance on set B. I want to have a good performance on set B and so I can achieve a comparable performance on set C (I guess).

The training process includes 2 steps:

1. Apply fine-tuning on set A for 10 epochs (because overfitting happens after 10 epochs). I used the VGG16 architecture (weights initialized from ImageNet) and modify the last fully connected layers from 1000-> 7 classes.
2. Finally evaluate on set B

Results: Almost the predictions on 20-29 and 30-39 years old.

I guess there is the imbalanced dataset for fine tuning.

My real questions are:

1. How to create the balanced dataset that we can utilize the benefit of set B?
2. The process that I did training is correct or not?

Note that: The images from set B is low quality than set A.

How can I improve the performane for the model? Thank you for your suggestion. [This is the comparison 2 set A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW3Q6.png)

Comment: Just to clarify, the images on the set B are comparable in terms of clarity and shapes? I mean, the elements are isolated? I am not so concerned about quality but rather them having the same kind of background, the same number of people per picture.. etc.

The 1st thing I would do is taking out some pictures from test A and trying your classification algorithm with those, which we know satisfy some kind of image criteria that makes them elegible for the training. If they work fine, I would blame your pictures on test B.

Comment: The images on set B are purely person faces. Only one face per one image. For more information, the distribution of set B and set A are different and bias toward a certain age.